# how to setup VS 2010 to allow debugging of Silverlight 3 and Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0

I have some code which is in Silverlight 3. I am unable to move to SL4 at this time.
I would however like to use VS 2010 to do my SL 3 development... and SL4 development.
The idea of both runtimes coexisting on 1 machine i thought I heard Microsoft got 
right this time in VS 2010.

is this correct? 
if yes, then Where can I find the instructions how to set this up?

thanks for any help you can provide,

Sincerely,
J

Answer (score 2):

Silverlight is not side-by-side. VS 2010 provides multi-targeting support for the full .NET framework, which is side-by-side, but NOT Silverlight.

There can only be one version of the Silverlight plugin and runtime on the machine.

That said, if you want to *build* code targeting one or the other, that is possible by checking in the Silverlight versions to your source enlistment. [This post is a little outdated](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2009/03/sxs-sl2-sl3-building/) but provides an example for doing this for SL2 and SL3.

Comment: Hi Jeff,
Thanks for the response. I figured that was the answer, but thought maybe there was some uh 'technique' that might be a work around. I'll take a look at the link you provided.